# How to embed the OEM key in Bios for laptop that do not have factory keys installed

Tags: windows-10, bios, oem

I have tried to edit an MSDN file in ACPI tab with RWEverything program.
But failed

I have a key that I ordered as an Windows 10 OEM, but when reinstalling Windows it gets lost and I have to re-enter it every time.

Is there any way for me to embed the keys in Bios?

Comment: Just select 'I don't have key' during installation. As already answered by harrymc, your clean install of Windows 10 will activate itself again using Digital Entitlement fetched from MS activation servers (as long as hardware fingerprint will match, i.e. you have not made considerable changes to your hardware)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for you to embed anything in the BIOS.
You could slipstream the product key into the installation media,
but this requires some knowledge.

Anyway, Windows 10 will activate itself after the installation.
If you have already installed Windows 10 on the device using a key,
you never have to enter the key again - keys are held on Microsoft's servers
which prevents a key being used more than once and makes things easier for
legitimate re-installs. The name for it is "digital entitlement".